# Creating Base58 public key & private key in Java?

Tags: private-key, public-key, bitcoinj, java, base58

How can I create a base58 private key and public key in Java? I'm pretty familiar with Java and I have the bitcoinj-minimal code, but it's not clear to me how I can generate a base58 key pair from the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
com.google.bitcoin.core.ECKey key = new com.google.bitcoin.core.ECKey(); // keypair
byte[] pub = key.getPublicKey(); // byte array

String prv; 
prv = key.getPrivateKeyEncoded(com.google.bitcoin.core.NetworkParameters.prodNet());
```